# Extremely slow performance on Azure VM's

Tags: azure

We have sold our first 2 small Azure real world implementations and have set them all up and are now getting hit with extremely bad feedback from the clients over performance.

One of them is setup as the following:

```
  Domain Controller – A2
  Terminal Server – A3
```

The terminal server is on an A3 plan (as it’s only a micro client of 2-4 concurrent users) and is horrendously slow. It takes 10-15 seconds to load websites in Internet Explorer (even during testing today it took 10 seconds to load sites such as Telstra's site or Sydney Morning Heralds site).

It also takes on average 8 seconds to load Microsoft Excel (without even loading a file). This is a vanilla install of Excel 2013 on Server 2012 R2 with the RDS role. We initially advised the client they should be fine on an A2 plan, however after they first complained about speeds, we moved them to A3 which made next to no discernible difference (and task manager is showing the machine not even coming close to using any resources).

Performance testing  is showing that the disk subsystems are slower than our desktop SATA machines – which could be related (which a quick Google search of “Azure slow disk io” shows that we aren’t alone here).

Our team here have run up an Amazon instance (with smaller specs than the A3 plan) and it is lightning fast doing the exact same things. We have also benchmarked on another Virtual Machine host that we used to use as we still have clients there from before we decided to start selling Azure and they are also lightning fast doing the same things.

In this particular case, the speeds they are getting are much, much slower than the 5 year old server that was replaced, which doesn’t bode too well for us unfortunately.

Another one of our clients other clients has exactly the same slow performance on their RDS server, especially around browsing the Internet. Speed tests on both show huge amount of speed (i.e. 500Mbit +) but daily usage doesn’t reflect that at all. It honestly feels like the Internet is operating at dial up speeds.

We've purchased a developer support pack and tried to lodge support instances, however it keeps crashing at the end of creating the request saying "Cannot log a support request at this time. Please contact Microsoft via phone and lodge an Azure request". We try calling via phone and they say they can't lodge them and we have to do it online.

We're desperate here for some help. Can anyone point us in the right direction?

Our guys have spent about 20 hours on this issue and everything points back to the Azure VM's just being super slow compared to other cloud providers (Amazon etc).

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow (it's about infrastructure, not programming).

Comment: Apologies, first time poster and was directed here from the Azure web page.

Comment: If the IOPS are the limiting factor, have you considered adding multiple data disks to your vm and striping them into a single volume? I believe you will be charged only for the actual data used, regardless of the disk size, at this tier of storage, so there's no real reason not to put the maximum number of allowed disks into your vm.

Comment: I'm not sure it's IOPS causing the problem, although it definitely could be. Even with just 1 user logged into the server, opening things like Excel (even without opening a file), Outlook and browsing the Internet is very slow. It seems to be slower at some times than others as well. With this server doing absolutely nothing (no scheduled tasks etc) it really feels like the underlying infrastructure causing the problem.

Comment: Try logging the support ticket using Internet Explorer

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  Upload speeds today are terrible also.

Answer (score 14):

Azure disks are terribly slow. There is a service option called "Premium storage" which should increase the IOPS drastically. Waiting that, I would create a separate volume on top of storage spaces (using as many disks as the VM size allows) in order to get max iops. (8 disks = 8x500 IOPS). Moving the user profiles to that disk should help.

Comment: Thanks Trondh, we've noticed that as well, however even so, it shouldn't take Excel 8 seconds to load and it shouldn't make web browsing as slow as it is.

I remember a time when we had to run a clients virtualised server (VHD) on an actual USB drive and even it wasn't this slow (and had at least triple the users). 

I've read a few people doing that storage spaces work around to try and get some more speed - we will give it a go as well, however I'm not too sure if this will increase things like Excel opening and browsing web pages?

Thanks again for your reply!

Answer (score 14):

I have seen both AWS and AZURE and AZURE is dead slow on drive performance while AWS is fairly snappy.  In my opinion, Azure is a terribly inferior product to AWS and that is simply the cause of many problems you would not have on AWS.

Comment: I think offering facts and not unverified opinions might be more helpful here. It's not that you're wrong, you're just not offering anything demonstrably factual for anyone to agree with your opinion about.

Comment: Azure performance is garbage, it's a fact @danno

Comment: I just observed what @william-egge wrote above. I tried running my spring boot app on Azure VM today and spent quite a while figuring out why no output is showing in the logs. Later on I realized that the VM is painfully slow. The first line of output showed up more than a few minutes later and the app startup took more than 5 minutes. It takes only a few seconds to startup on AWS VM.

Comment: Also confirming, CPU and memory are ok, but disks are very slow compared to other companies or real hardware, example unzipping and 1mb archive took 2 minutes on a new machine

Answer (score 6):

I set up a SharePoint development environment using my free MSDN Ultimate subscription.

I went with a **D12 machine type** ([see Virtual Machine sizes](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/)).
It should offer decent IOPS. At least with the **D-series** there is the promise of "local" SSDs. MSDN documentation contains some numbers on that: [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx).

Installing StyleCop took hours.
Installing Resharper did not even complete.. some Visual Studio component which needs to be called during the setup "did not return in a timely fashion"... I'm not talking seconds here. I'm talking about several tens of minutes of waiting!

Opening the "add/remove programs" window never completes...

I spent 2 hours trying to installed two tiny pieces of software while nothing else was running on the machine. Seriously... that's nowhere even remotely near "productive".

The virtual machine has been deallocated for a few months. I started it up yesterday and shut it down at the end of my investigations (doing some software development). Today I wanted to continue where I left of. Unfortunately the performance degraded since yesterday. I was hoping it would actually perform better due to more frequent use (second day in a row).

That's a really sad picture. Fortunately my subscription is "free"...

Comment: The local SSD is the temporary local drive, not the OS or data drive. If you want SSD performance use a DS-series machine and setup up its storage on premium storage.

Answer (score 6):

i ran a comparison on an Azure VM versus my own personal development workstation.

[image]

The image above shows the specs between my personal developer workstation and our VM server in Azure.

Both machines are  running 16 Gig of Ram, 64 bit windows and both running SSD drives.   My i7 processor is 3 ghz versus the 2.2 ghz processor on the azure box.

My development workstation can restore a sql database backup in 1 minute 30 seconds. 
In azure  it takes 22 minutes and 4 seconds to restore the exact same backup file.

I have contacted microsoft about this to see if they can offer any insight.  My local dev workstation is just running on a single C:\ ssd drive with no striping etc.

The above test was conducted on the a2 v2 vm sized hardware and the a2m v2 sized vm hardware.  In both instances the database restored in 22 minutes.

[image]

[image]

Restoring on the d4s v3 line of hardware dropped the restore time drastically to 9 minutes.

[image]

So far none of these VMS come anywhere close to the speed of my personal development workstation running sql server on a single ssd drive with basic windows 10 pro.

Comment: Wow, this makes a lot of sense based on the terrible performance we are experiencing